# Excluding functions from GCC link-time optimizer (LTO)

Tags: gcc, pragma

Does anyone know if there is a way to exclude certain functions from the GCC link-time optimizer? We are testing the use of GCC link-time optimizer in a small ARM embedded project and with it enabled, a decent amount of incredibly valuable flash is freed up, but it is causing serious performance issues with a handful of functions.

I am trying to figure out if there is a way using #pragma or something similar to exclude certain functions from the link-time optimizer. This would allow us to take advantage of most of the flash savings without the performance hit on those functions.

Comment: Make them always inline

Comment: BTW what outdated micro are you using? $3 ones have 512kb which is a lot.

Comment: Not convinced this it the right way to handle it, but you could look at attributes like noipa (or the weaker attributes its documentation lists).

Comment: @PeterJ_01 We are using a NXP Kinetis EA micro. It is an automotive chip and pennies matter in terms of cost for this project. I appreciate the thought but I would not have asked the question if simply moving to a bigger part was an option (trust me, I'd love to go bigger).

Comment: So how LTO can free make flash usage smaller? Only by not inlining the function.

Comment: I see this is an old question but since there is no answer I suggest as solution. If you place the functions that should be untouched by LTO in a separate source file, and compile it without the LTO flags, ld will not be able to do any LTO on those functions.